# OpenLayers snap to multipoint layer

Tags: openlayers, snapping, multipoint

Implementing snap interaction by getting snap points as features in layer. The draw interaction does not snap to displayed nodes. What is wrong?

```js
snap_nodes = MULTIPOINT((350095.29 650021.37),(350097.44 650021.59),(350098.11 650025.77),(350098.72 650028.78),(350099.32 650030.98),(350099.52 650031.48),(350100.03 650032.29),(350100.63 650033.19),(350101.64 650034.2),(350102.35 650034.7),(350103.05 650035),(350103.25 650035.1),(350104.16 650035.21))

 {   let wkt = new WKT();

const geometry = wkt.readGeometry(snap_nodes,
   {      
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:27700',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
}
);
  let feature = new Feature(geometry);
  style: new Style({
    stroke : new Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 2
    }),
    fill : new Fill({color:'red'})
  })
  const snapVectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features: [feature]
  });
 const snapLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: snapVectorSource
  });     
 this._map.addLayer(snapLayer);

 const snapInteraction = new Snap({
  source : snapVectorSource
 }
 )
 snapInteraction.setActive(true);
this._map.addInteraction(snapInteraction);
const extent = [349900, 649900, 350100, 650100];

const drawInteraction = new Draw({
  type: GeometryType.POLYGON,
  source: <VectorSource>snapVectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke : new Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      width: this._strokeWidth
    })
  })
})
drawInteraction.setActive(true);
this._map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
this._map.getView().fit(extent, {
    duration: 1000,  
    padding: [10, 10, 10, 10] 
  });

 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [docs of the snap interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Snap-Snap.html) this is not mentioned, but if you look at the [snap interaction example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/snap.html), you can read:

> The snap interaction must be added last, as it needs to be the first
> to handle the pointermove event.

This means you have to add snap interaction to the map after adding draw interaction to make snap work during drawing.

There's one other thing in the code that seems to be wrong. Since your snap points geometry is converted to `EPSG:3857` this means your view is also in this projection, which means you have to convert your `extent` to the same projection (plain JS):

```
map.getView().fit(ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:3857'), {
  duration: 1000,  
  padding: [10, 10, 10, 10] 
});
```

Comment: thanks. Adding snap after draw interaction solved the problem.